# Removing conductive silver paste from a stainless steel plate

Tags: experimental-physics

I've been doing some STM experiments on TMD material held down with silver paste.
is there any recommend solvent for removing the paste? 
I was going to use IPA or ethanol in a sonic bath...any thoughts?

Comment: Anything that doesn't interact (i.e. damage or corrode) stainless steel is fine.

Comment: Try acetone if water and ethanol don't work. Oftentimes one of those three takes care of most bonds/glues.